# Question about this problem. Find $a\in\mathbb{R}$ so that function $f$ is continous in $x=\pi/6$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $f:[0;2\pi]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=2\sin(x)-\cos(x)$, when $x\in[0;\pi/6]$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{3}\tan(x)+a$, when $a\in(\pi/6;2\pi]$. Determine $a$ so $f$ is continuous at $x=\pi/6$. Question: Can $f$ even be continuous if the domain is $[0,2\pi]$ and the function isn't defined at $x=\pi/6$? and why is there at the second function condition as $a\in(\pi/6,2\pi]$ and not as $x\in(\pi/6,2\pi]$

Comment: write using mathjax